# PostgreSQL Docker container does not communicate correclty with another one

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have the docker.yml file as below:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    db:
        image: postgres:9.4
        environment: 
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
    result:
        image: result
        ports: 
            - 8080:80
```

When I run "docker-compose up" for the file, I am getting the following errors:

```
result-db-1      | FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
result-db-1      | DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
```

And I do not understand why, because I am specifying the password for postgres and "result" container should know this password, isn't it?

Of course, I can add an environment like the below:

```
POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust"
```

But is it safe and is it a good solution?
Or a better solution can be applied here?

Answer (score 0):

try `depends_on: - db`
And where is your Dockerfile?
You need to create jar

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    db:
        image: postgres:9.4
        container_name: db
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment: 
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
    result:
        image: result
        restart: unless-stopped
        build:
         context: ./
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
        depends_on:
         - db
        ports: 
            - 8080:80
```

```
//Dockerfile
//try this Dockerfile
//this is java 8 but you can change it

FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

this might help you [Postgres in docker returns 'password authentication failed (..) roles "username" does not exist'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65301290/postgres-in-docker-returns-password-authentication-failed-roles-username?rq=1)

Comment: Did not help, also not clear where is the issue
As I can see I correctly passing password for Postgresql